# Managing Virtual Macs on a closed network

Tags: mac, vmware, apple-remote-desktop

I have a lab of VMWare virtual Macs on a network with no Internet access.  What options do i have for managing these Macs, other than one at a time?  I am looking at ARD and JAMF at the moment...

Comment: So OS X is the virtual environment?  What are the host computers?

Comment: Hosts are Late 2013 Mac Pros running ESXi 5.5, virtual Macs are running 10.9.5 and 10.10.1.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why have a Mac Pro run a virtual OS X environment?

Comment: Apple allows for virtual Macs when the software is run on Apple hardware.  This affords us the luxury of having test Macs that we may quickly reset, and greater flexibility is setting up those Macs.

Comment: I've since parsed out how to get ARD to work just fine within this virtual environment.  Provided the network does not span across too many vLANS, ARD will be just the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Remote Desktop turns out to be the answer.  It is important that ARD have a separate administrative user account, and I recommend that the account be hidden from users' view.